# Non-additivity of intersection forms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Given two oriented $4k$-manifolds $X_1$ and $X_2$, Novikov additivity tells us that 
$$
\sigma(X_1 \sharp X_2) = \sigma(X_1) + \sigma(X_2).$$

More generally, if we glue the boundaries of two such manifolds $X_1$ and $X_2$ via a orientation-reversing diffeomorphism (or even just part of the boundaries  - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106237/additivity-of-signature)) then Novikov additivity holds.  [Wall](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/wall6.pdf) has famously analyzed the failure of additivity when we glue along a submanifold of the boundary that itself has boundary.

I am interested in how this story extends to intersection forms.  In particular:

> What can be said about the relationship between the intersection form $Q_{X}$, where $X = X_1 \cup_\phi X_2$ where $\phi$ is an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism between closed submanifolds of the boundary, and the intersection forms $Q_{X_1}$ and $Q_{X_2}$?

I know that additivity of intersection forms holds in the case where the boundaries of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both homology spheres and they are glued along their entire boundary - so in particular, $Q_{X_1 \sharp X_2} = Q_{X_1} + Q_{X_2}$.  I wonder if there is some error term in the general case that has been identified.  For what it's worth, I am primarily interested in the case where $k=1$.